# How do i find the convergence of $f(n)/2^{n}$

Tags: probability, statistics, convergence-divergence

I need to find the convergence of $\frac{f(n)}{2^{n}}$ where $f(n)$ is the $n^{th}$ element of the Fibonacci sequence. I have a very large N (>1000) and computing the value is numerically difficult. 
Any help is greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Use [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Relation_to_the_golden_ratio) form involving golden ratio.

Comment: Why is this tagged ```probability```and ```statistics```?

Comment: Are you interested in the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{2^n}$, [which is zero](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+of+4%5E%28-n%29+%2F+sqrt%285%29+%28+%281+%2B+sqrt%285%29%29%5En+-+%281+-+sqrt%285%29%29%5En%29+for+n+to+infty), or the convergence speed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114800/infinite-series-fibonacci-2n) you know that $\sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{f(n)}{2^n} = 2$, therefore, we neccessary have $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{2^n} = 0$.

---

My **not yet finished** attempt to show the limit statement goes like this:
\begin{align}
\frac{f(n)}{2^n}
& = \frac{1}{2^n} \cdot \frac{\left(\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n - \left(\frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n}{\sqrt{5}}
= \frac{4^{-n}}{\sqrt{5}} \left( (1 + \sqrt{5})^n - (1 - \sqrt{5})^n \right) \\
& = \frac{4^{-n}}{\sqrt{5}} \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} (\sqrt{5})^k(1 - (-1)^n)
\end{align}
Now if we assume that $n$ is even we can continue:
$$
\frac{f(n)}{2^n}
= \frac{4^{-n}}{\sqrt{5}} \sum_{k = 0}^{\frac{n}{2}}2 \binom{n}{2k} (\sqrt{5})^{2k} 
= \frac{4^{-n}}{\sqrt{5}} \sum_{k = 0}^{\frac{n}{2}}2 \binom{n}{2k} (\sqrt{5})^{2k} 
= \frac{2^{1-2n}}{\sqrt{5}} \sum_{k = 0}^{\frac{n}{2}} \binom{n}{2k} 5^k 
$$
We'd now need some sort of asymptotic estimate to take care of the sum.