# Prove that $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{F_{n}}{2^{n}}= \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers

I came up with this identity in high school, and I can't remember how I proved it :P  Does anyone know how I would go about doing this?

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{F_{n}}{2^{n}}= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n}}$$

Comment: There is a link to a generalization on this page, at the right.

Comment: Ah, cool.  Is there a way to prove this using generating functions?  I think that's what I did originally.

Comment: Please give us the initial conditions to the specific Fibonacci sequence you have in mind. I think this statement maybe ambiguous as is.

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88529) seems to be the question André is referring to. @This, usually without stated initial conditions, everyone just takes the default one...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just for fun, here is a proof using probability.

Let $N$ be the number of times you 
toss a fair coin until you get two heads in a row.

Here are some outcomes for small $N$ values:

- $N=2\quad$ HH
- $N=3\quad$ THH
- $N=4\quad$ TTHH, HTHH
- $N=5\quad$ TTTHH, THTHH, HTTHH
- $N=6\quad$    TTTTHH, TTHTHH, THTTHH, HTTTHH, HTHTHH
- etc.

The outcomes of length $n$ are formed in two ways: by sticking a T
in front of an outcome of length $n-1$ or sticking HT in front of 
an outcome of length $n-2$. Thus,  the number of outcomes
of length $n$ is $F_{n-1}$.

Since the probabilities must add to one, we have 
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty {F_{n-1}\over 2^n}=1$$
which is equivalent to the required identity.

Comment: Whoa, that's crazy! I would have never thought to look at it that way.

Answer (score 7):

The generating series for the Fibonacci sequence is $$\frac{x}{1-x-x^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty F_nx^n.$$Now show that the series converges at $x=\frac12$ (using the ratio test for example) and to conclude that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{F_n}{2^n}=2$.