# Summation involving Fibonacci numbers

Tags: summation, fibonacci-numbers

Find:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{F_{2k}F_{n-k}}{10^n} 
$$
where $F_n$ is $n$-th Fibonacci number.

Comment: Have you used generating functions before?  If so, you just need to find the ordinary generating functions for $F_n$ and $F_{2n}$.  Then multiply them and plug in $x = 1/10$.

Comment: This has a basic answer at this [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/179855/two-sums-with-fibonacci-numbers).

Answer (score 3):

We have:
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}F_{2k}x^k = \frac{x}{1-3x+x^2} \tag{1}$$
and
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}F_{k} x^k = \frac{x}{1-x-x^2}\tag{2} $$
hence:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{10^n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}F_{2k}F_{n-k}=\left.\frac{x^2}{(1-3x+x^2)(1-x-x^2)}\right|_{x=\frac{1}{10}} = \color{red}{\frac{100}{6319}}.\tag{3}$$

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{%
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\,\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{F_{2k}\, F_{n - k} \over 10^{n}}} & =
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}F_{2k}\, \sum_{n = k}^{\infty}{F_{n - k} \over 10^{n}} =
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{F_{2k} \over 10^{k}}
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{F_{n} \over 10^{n}}
\\[5mm] & =
\bracks{\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}F_{n}\pars{1 \over 10}^{n}}
\bracks{\half\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{F_{k}\pars{1 \over\root{10}}^{k}} +
\half\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{F_{k} \pars{-\,{1 \over \root{10}}}^{k}}}
\end{align}

---

With the *Fibonacci generating function*
$\ds{\,\mc{F}\pars{z} = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}F_{n}\,z^{n} =
{z \over 1 - z - z^{2}}}$:
\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{%
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\,\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{F_{2k}\, F_{n - k} \over 10^{n}}} & =
\half\,\mc{F}\pars{1 \over 10}\bracks{\mc{F}\pars{1 \over \root{10}} +
\mc{F}\pars{-\,{1 \over \root{10}}}} = \color{#f00}{100 \over 6319}
\approx 0.0158
\end{align}

> Note that $\ds{\quad\mc{F}\pars{1 \over 10} = {10 \over 89}\quad
> \mbox{and}\quad
> \,\mc{F}\pars{\pm\,{1 \over \root{10}}} = {10 \pm 9\root{10} \over 71}}$.