# Find the sum of an infinite series of Fibonacci numbers divided by doubling numbers.

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, limits, fibonacci-numbers

How would I find the sum of an infinite number of fractions, where there are Fibonacci numbers as the numerators (increasing by one term each time) and numbers (starting at one) which double each time as the denominators?

I'm assuming this has something to do with limits.

Comment: Wow, that points to the more general case [$\sum F_n/p^n$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88529/prove-the-fibonacci-sum-sum-limits-n-0-infty-fracf-npn-fracpp)

Answer (score 5):

Using Moivre-Binet
$$
F_n = \frac{\phi^n - \psi^n}{\phi - \psi}
$$
with $\phi$ and $\psi$ being the positive and negative root of the golden ratio equation $x^2 - x - 1 = 0$,
we get

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{F_n}{2^n}
&= 
\frac{1}{\phi - \psi} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\phi^n-\psi^n}{2^n} \\
&= 
\frac{1}{\phi - \psi} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{\phi}{2}\right)^n -
\frac{1}{\phi - \psi} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{\psi}{2}\right)^n  \\
&= 
\frac{1}{\phi - \psi} \frac{1}{1 - \frac{\phi}{2} } - 
\frac{1}{\phi - \psi} \frac{1}{1 - \frac{\psi}{2} } \\
&= 
\frac{2}{\phi - \psi} \left( 
\frac{1}{2 - \phi} - \frac{1}{2 - \psi} 
\right) \\
&= 
\frac{2}{\phi - \psi} \left( 
\frac{(2-\psi) - (2-\phi)}{(2 - \phi)(2-\psi)}
\right) \\
&= 
\frac{2}{\phi - \psi} \left( 
\frac{\phi - \psi}{4 - 2 \phi - 2 \psi + \phi \psi}
\right) \\
&= 
\frac{2}{4 - 2 (\phi + \psi) + \phi \psi} \\
&= 
\frac{2}{4 - 2 + (-1)} \\
&= 2
\end{align}
Note: The geometric series converge because $\lvert \phi/2 \rvert < 1$ and $\lvert \psi/2 \rvert < 1$.

**Appendix:**
$$
x^2 - x - 1 = 0 \iff x = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2}
$$
Thus 
$$
\phi + \psi = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2} + \frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2} = 1
$$
and
$$
\phi \psi = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2} \frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2} = \frac{1 - 5}{4} = -1
$$

Comment: $\psi\phi=$psience phiction

Comment: You have summed $0/1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 2/8 + 3/16 + ...$ , but I think $1/1 + 1/2 + 2/4 + 3/8 + ...$ was wanted.

Comment: The question is vague about the first index of the Fibonacci series. I chose $0$ but I would also accept $1$.

Answer (score 2):

This is a standard infinite sequence problem.
It starts with just this:
 $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{F_n}{2^n}=$$
 $$\frac11+\frac12+\frac24+\frac38+\frac5{16}+\frac8{32}+...$$

---

let S equal the sequence of fractions:

$S=\frac11+\frac12+\frac24+\frac38+\frac5{16}+\frac8{32}+...$

Divide by 2 and get:

$\frac{S}2=\frac12+\frac14+\frac28+\frac3{16}+\frac5{32}+...$

Subtract the first from the second to get:

$S-\frac{S}2=1+\frac02+\frac14+\frac18+\frac2{16}+\frac3{32}+...$

Simplify:

$\frac{S}2=1+\frac14+\frac18+\frac2{16}+\frac3{32}+...$

Multiply both sides by two:

$S=2+\frac12+\frac14+\frac2{8}+\frac3{16}+...$

$2S=4+\frac11+\frac12+\frac24+\frac3{8}+...$

Recognize S from above:

$2S=4+S$

Subtract S from both sides:

$S=4$

Answer (score 1):

I assume the sum you want to compute is
$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{F_n}{2^n}$$
where $F_n$ is the $n$'th Fibonacci number ($F_0=F_1=1$ and $F_n = F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$ for $n\ge 2$). One simple way of computing this is to use the closed form of $F_n$, namely
$$F_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\Biggl(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\Biggr)^{n}-\Biggl(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\Biggr)^{n}\right).$$
Inserting this into the sum, and using that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a^n = \frac{1}{1-a}$ for $|a|<1$, you get
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{F_n}{2^n}&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\Biggl(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{4}\Biggr)^{n}-\Biggl(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{4}\Biggr)^{n}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\frac{1}{1-(1+\sqrt{5})/4}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\frac{1}{1-(1-\sqrt{5})/4)}\\
&= 2
\end{align}

Comment: Your answer should be $2$. Take a closer look at your closed form.

Comment: Thank you, I'll fix that now.

Comment: The answer should be 4, assuming that the first term is 1/1 and not 0/1.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a reasonably efficient low-tech approach (i.e., not using Binet's formula or generating functions).

Prove by induction that
$$ \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{F_k}{2^k} = 2 - \frac{F_{n+3}}{2^n} \tag{1} $$
and that
$$ nF_n \le 2^n \tag{2} $$
(For (2) you might find it convenient to assume $n\ge 6$.)  From (2) it follows that $\frac{F_{n+3}}{2^n} \le \frac8{n+3} \to 0$, so the partial sums in (1) converge.