# Calculate the value of $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{2}{8}+\frac{3}{16}+....+\frac{F_n}{2^n}+....$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, contest-math, fibonacci-numbers

The Fibonacci sequence starts with 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, ... .(Start from the 3rd term,
each term is the sum of the two previous terms). Let $F_n$ be the $n$th term of this sequence. $S$ is defined as $S=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{2}{8}+\frac{3}{16}+....+\frac{F_n}{2^n}+....$
Calculate the value of $S$

I have no idea how to solve this, hints aswell as solutions would be appreciated

Taken from the 2013 AITMO

Comment: Thanks for posting this.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/114800/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/988939/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/137063/42969 – all found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bn%3D0%7D%5E%5Cinfty%20%5Cfrac%7BF_n%7D%7B2%5En%7D%24&p=1)

Comment: Are you coming india for the itmo test this 14th .

Comment: @AkshajBansal yeah I am

Comment: Oh great i am of city montessori school gomtinagar only and would be taking part in the competion all the best for the exam will see you soon

Comment: From which country do you hail?

Comment: Although this is not exactly the same question but this video provides a derivation for your result see here https://youtu.be/i2rDbfhRHok

Comment: @AkshajBansal I am coming from South Africa, see you soon, wish you all the best

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: if you know that the generating function for the Fibonacci sequence is:

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty F_nx^n = \frac{x}{1-x-x^2}$

then you can substitute $x=\frac 1 2$ and you immediately have

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{F_n}{2^n} = \frac{\frac 1 2}{1-\frac 1 2 -\frac 1 4} =2 $

So to answer questions like this quickly, you should learn about generating functions.

Comment: I think the OP looks for the *steps* towards a solution ; the knowledge of the generating function is *no* pre-knowledge for the OP, I think.

Comment: @GottfriedHelms So this might prompt the OP to learn about generating functions ... I have edited my answer to make this clear.

Comment: Very well! Upvoted.

Comment: +1 for using a generating function.  Readers not familiar with generating functions might be interested in this question and its answers: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3142386/how-can-i-learn-about-generating-functions/3142387

Answer (score 6):

Replace $F_n$ with $F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$, now you have two series that are both similar to $S$

Comment: To expand on this, show that $S(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty F_kx^k$ is given by $S(x)-xS(x)-x^2S(x)=1$ for all *small* complex numbers $x$.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: $$F_n{={\frac {\Phi ^{n}-\Psi ^{n}}{\sqrt {5}}}={\frac {1}{\sqrt {5}}}\left(\left({\frac {1+{\sqrt {5}}}{2}}\right)^{n}-\left({\frac {1-{\sqrt {5}}}{2}}\right)^{n}\right)}$$

$$S = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{F_n}{2^n}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\left(\dfrac{\Phi}{2}\right)^n- \left(\dfrac{\Psi}{2}\right)^n\right]$$

Comment: The sign in the middle should be $-$.

Comment: @Dr Zafar Ahmend DSc Thank you for spotting the typo.

Answer (score 1):

$$F_n=\frac{a^n-b^n}{\sqrt{5}},~ a+b=1, ~ab=-1,~ a,b=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}.$$
The required sim $$ s=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{F_n}{2^n}= \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left ( \frac{a^n}{2^n}-\frac{b^n}{2^n} \right) =\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\frac{a}{2-a}-\frac{b}{2-b}\right)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}~\frac{2(a-b)}{4-2(a+b)+ab}=\frac{2 \sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{5}}=2.$$

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the hint of @empy2:

$$\begin{array}{rlll}
  S(z) &= 1 + & 1z +& 2z^2 + 3z^3 + 5z^4 + ... \\\
z S(z) &=     & 1z +& 1z^2 + 2z^3 + 3z^4 + 5z^5 + ... \\\
S(z)-zS(z)-1 &=     && 1z^2 + 1z^3 + 2z^4 + 3z^5   \\\ 
\end{array} \\\
\begin{array}{rlll} \hline
S(z)-zS(z)-1 &= z^2 S(z) &\qquad & \phantom{sdfsdfsdfsdfs} \\\
S(z)(1-z-z^2)& =1 \\\
S(z) &= 1/(1-z-z^2) 
\end{array}
$$
Now insert $1/2$ for $z$ and compute $1/2 S(1/2)$