# For $\alpha, \beta$ the roots of $x^2-x-1=0$, define $a_n=\frac{\alpha^n-\beta^n}{\alpha-\beta}$ and $b_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n+1}$. Then ...

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recurrence-relations, quadratics

> Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be the roots of $x^{2}-x-1=0$, with $\alpha>\beta$. For all positive integers $n$, define $a_{n}=\frac{a^{n}-\beta^{n}}{\alpha-\beta}, \quad n \geq 1, b_{1}=1$ and $b_{n}=a_{n-1}+a_{n+1}, n \geq 2$. Then which of the following options is/are correct?
>
> (A) $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{b_{n}}{10^{n}}=\frac{8}{89}$
>
> (B) $b_{n}=\alpha^{n}+\beta^{n}$ for all $n \geq 1$
>
> (C) $a_{1}+a_{2}+a_{3}+\ldots .+a_{n}=a_{n+2}-1$ for all $n \geq 1$
>
> (D) $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_{n}}{10^{n}}=\frac{10}{89}$

I tried using basic algebraic manipulations and getting certain recurrence relations and proceeding. But the irony is this question was asked in an exam with max time 3 minutes per question. And I can't get anywhere even less than 15 minutes.

Any intelligent techniques will be appreciated which might not have clicked to me.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! This is a JEE question, the answer to which is available on a ton of different websites. Have you checked them?

Comment: *"I didn't like their method. Like I said I appreciate shorter/smarter approaches."* Please [edit your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4425036/edit) to describe the method(s) you don't like, so that people don't waste time giving duplicate responses. Besides, how can anyone tell what counts as "shorter/smarter approaches" without a basis for comparison?

Comment: This is plainly [Binet's formula](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinetsFibonacciNumberFormula.html) for Fibonacci sequence, itself connected to golden ratio $\alpha$...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prove the Fibonacci sum $\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{F_n}{p^n} = \frac{p}{p^2-p-1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88529/how-to-prove-the-fibonacci-sum-sum-limits-n-0-infty-fracf-npn-fr)

Comment: See as well these generating functions https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1364134/305862

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A first remark is that, recognizing [Binet's formula](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinetsFibonacciNumberFormula.html), the $a_n$ can be identified with Fibonacci numbers $F_n$.

Using **generating functions/series** is quite natural in such a context.

- The $a_n=F_n$  have the classical generating function:

$$F(x):=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}F_kx^k=\dfrac{x}{1-x-x^2}=\underbrace{1}_{F_1}x+\underbrace{1}_{F_2}x^2+\underbrace{2}_{F_3}x^3+\underbrace{3}_{F_4}x^4+...\tag{1}$$

(We can consider by assumption that $F_0=0$...)

Setting $x=\dfrac{1}{10}$ in (1) validates affirmation (D).

- The $b_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n+1}$ called **Lucas numbers** $L_n$, have the following generating function:

$$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}(F_{k-1}+F_{k+1})x^k =\left(\frac{1}{x}+x\right)F(x)-\color{red}{1}=\dfrac{x+2x^2}{1-x-x^2}, \tag{2}$$

whose Taylor expansion is:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}L_{k}x^k =x+3x^2+4x^3+7x^4+11x^5+21x^6+\cdots$$

setting $x=\dfrac{1}{10}$ gives $\dfrac{12}{89}$ (as found by Ivan Kaznacheyeu using other means) invalidating affirmation (A). [NB: the presence of correcting term $\color{red}{1}$ is understood when writing the very first terms of (1)].

Final remark: Indeed, it looks strange that these questions are asked in the framework of a very limited range of time. The generating formula has to be known... Morever, what about less known Lucas numbers ?

Comment: As a high schooler we aren't expected to know Lucas numbers. Especially remarking that it's just an entrance to IITs in India.

Comment: reply to the final remark: Hope you were a prof on the paper setting committee, Brutal 18 Q's in 1 hour.

Comment: All right. Hoping that my answer has brought some light...

Comment: Btw about generating functions, a reference is the well written book "Generatingfunctionology" by H. Wilf.

Comment: Plus 1 for editing such an old answer.

Answer (score 1):

$a_n=\frac1{\alpha-\beta}(\alpha^n-\beta^n)$

$\alpha^{n+2}=\alpha^n\alpha^2=$ $\alpha^n(\alpha+1)=\alpha^{n+1}+\alpha^n$

$a_{n+2}=a_{n+1}+a_n$

$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i=a_{n+2}-1$ can be easily shown by induction.

$\frac{a_n}{10^n}=\frac1{\alpha-\beta}\left((\frac{\alpha}{10})^n-(\frac{\beta}{10})^n\right)$

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{10^n}=\frac1{\alpha-\beta}\left(\frac{\alpha}{10}\frac{1}{1-\frac{\alpha}{10}}-\frac{\beta}{10}\frac{1}{1-\frac{\beta}{10}}\right)=$ $\frac1{\alpha-\beta}\left(\frac{\alpha}{10-\alpha}-\frac{\beta}{10-\beta}\right)=\frac{10}{100-10(\alpha+\beta)+\alpha\beta}=\frac{10}{100-10+1}=\frac{10}{89}$

$\alpha^n+\beta^n=\frac{\alpha^{n+1}-\beta^{n+1}}{\alpha-\beta}-\alpha\beta\frac{\alpha^{n-1}-\beta^{n-1}}{\alpha-\beta}=a_{n+1}+a_{n-1}=b_n$, $n\geq 2$

$b_1=1=\alpha+\beta$

$\frac{b_n}{10^n}=\left(\frac{\alpha}{10}\right)^n+\left(\frac{\beta}{10}\right)^n$

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{b_n}{10^n}=\frac{\alpha}{10}\frac{1}{1-\frac{\alpha}{10}}+\frac{\beta}{10}\frac{1}{1-\frac{\beta}{10}}=$ $\frac{\alpha}{10-\alpha}+\frac{\beta}{10-\beta}=$ $\frac{10(\alpha+\beta)-2\alpha\beta}{100-10(\alpha+\beta)+\alpha\beta}=\frac{12}{89}$.

Comment: Have you seen my remark about Binet's formula and Fibonacci numbers ? Moreover, it can be considered as a consequence of this question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/88529/305862

Comment: Of course, it is almost obvious that $a_n$ is sequence of Fibonacci numbers. Result of linked question can be used for answering (D) part.

Comment: You are right. I hadn't read attentively the question. So, you are answering question (A) by the negative. Have I well understood ?

Comment: Yes, and I did't find error in my calculations, though I may be wrong. But $b_n \geq a_n$ which ensures me, that I must be right.

Comment: An alternative way to compute/confirm the value of series (A) is to use the result of (D)...

Comment: In fact, the $b_n$ are the [Lucas numbers](https://oeis.org/A000204) with generating function $\sum b_n x^n= \dfrac{x+2x^2}{1-x-x^2}$. Plugging $x=1/10$ gives indeed $12/89$.

Comment: Jean marie's comments itself opened a new world to me. That's what I was looking for!!