# What is the J-type continued fraction of the generating function of the Fibonacci numbers?

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, fibonacci-numbers, continued-fractions, orthogonal-polynomials

Let

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{ll}
\displaystyle 
F(z) 
&\displaystyle = \ 1 \ + \ z \ + \ 2z^2 \ + \ 3z^3 \ + \ 5z^4 
\ + \ \cdots \\
&\displaystyle = \ {1 \over {1 -z - z^2}}
\end{array}
\end{equation}

be the generating function of the Fibonacci numbers (along with its
presentation as a rational function). One can check that the associated semi-infinite *Hankel matrix*

\begin{equation}
H \ = \ \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 2 & 3  & 5  &  \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 5  & 8  &  \\
2 & 3 & 5 & 8  & 13 &  \\
3 & 5 & 8 & 13 & 21 &  \\
5 & 8 & 13 & 21 & 34 \\
& & & & & \ddots
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

of the Fibonacci sequence is positive semi-definite, i.e. the
principal, finite minors of $H$ are all non-negative: It is enough
(in fact equivalent) to check that all $k \times k$ principal, *contiguous* minors are non-negative for $k \geq 1$.
Using the Fibonacci recurrence
and row operations the reader can verify
that the value of each $2 \times 2$ principal, contiguous minor
is **one** and that the value of each $k \times k$ principal, contiguous
minor is **zero** for $k \geq 3$.

In light of this positive semi-definiteness, a
result of Alan Sokal
(see theorem 2.1 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.04498.pdf)
indicates that
the generating function $F(z)$ should have a presentation
as a J-type continued fraction, i.e. there must exist
a real number $\alpha_0 \geq 0$ along with two infinite
sequences

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{ll}
\displaystyle \underline{\beta} 
&\displaystyle = \ \big(\beta_1, \ \beta_2, \ \beta_3, \ \dots \big) 
\ \ \text{with $\beta_k \geq 0$ for all $k \geq 1$} \\
\displaystyle \underline{\gamma} 
&\displaystyle = \ \big(\gamma_0, \ \gamma_1, \ \gamma_2, \ \, \dots \big)
\ \ \text{with $\gamma_k \in \Bbb{R}$ for all $k \geq 0$} 
\end{array}
\end{equation}

such that

\begin{equation} 
F(z) \ = \ {\alpha_0 \over {1 - z \gamma_0 \ - \ {\displaystyle z^2 \beta_1 \over {\displaystyle 1 - z \gamma_1 \ - \ {z^2 \beta_2 \over {\displaystyle 1 - z \gamma_2 \ - \ {z^2 \beta_3 \over {\ddots}}}}}}}}
\end{equation}

**Question:** Is anyone familiar with this continued fraction? What are $\alpha_0$, $\underline{\beta}$, and $\underline{\gamma}$ exactly?

thanks, ines.

Post-Script: I would point out that the J-continued fraction introduced here seems quite different from the continued fraction discussed in

[conjectured new generating function of fibonacci numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1400244/conjectured-new-generating-function-of-fibonacci-numbers?rq=1) .

Comment: What about $\alpha_0=\gamma_0=\beta_1=1$ and all other numbers zero?