# Infinite geometric sum (asking for insight on an easier solution)

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, contest-math, generating-functions

Let the sequence $F$ be defined as: $F_1=F_2=1$ and $F_n=2F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$, for $n>2$. Evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{F_n}{10^n}$.

The obvious solution involves solving for the explicit formula for $F$ (using the standard linear recurrence technique): $F_n=(\frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{2})(1+\sqrt{2})^n-(\frac{\sqrt{2}+1}{2})(1-\sqrt{2})^n$. Then we can just split the sum into two infinite geometric series. The computation is annoying, but nonetheless straightforward.

I was wondering if there is any easier solution than solving for an explicit formula for $F$. Maybe there is one that only needs the recursive definition? Any comments are appreciated.

Comment: Closely related: [Prove that the infinite sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{F_{n}}{ 10 ^ n }$ converges to a rational number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2084429/prove-that-the-infinite-sum-sum-n-1-infty-fracf-n-10-n-converg) – see for example this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2084552/42969.

Comment: It's perhaps worth noting that there's nothing special about 10 here - all of the answers amount to (implicitly) finding the generating function $\mathcal{F}(x)=\sum_n F_n x^n $ and evaluating it at $x=\frac1{10}$

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Define $S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{{F_n}\over{10^n}}$.

For proving that $S$ exists, note that $F_n$ is strictly increasing since $F_1,F_2>0$. Therefore we can obtain that $F_n=2F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}\le 3F_{n-1}$. Now define $b_n={{F_n}\over{10^n}}$ thus we get here:
$${{b_{n+1}}\over{b_n}}={{F_{n+1}}\over{10F_n}}\le0.3<1$$
which implies on convergence according to *d'Alembert's ratio test*

After proving convergence we have:
$$
\begin{split}
S &= {1\over 10}
   + {1\over 100}
   + \sum_{n=3}^{\infty}{F_n\over{10^n}}\\
  &= {1\over 10}
   + {1\over 100}
   + \sum_{n=3}^{\infty}{{F_{n-2}+2F_{n-1}}\over{10^n}}\\
  &= {11\over 100}
   + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{{F_n}\over{10^{n+2}}}
   + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}{{F_n}\over{10^{n+1}}}\\
  &= {11\over 100}+{S\over 100}+{2S\over 10}-{2\over 100}\\
  &={{21S+9}\over 100} \implies S={9\over 79}
\end{split}
$$

Comment: Awesome solution!

Comment: That's very kind of you!

Comment: I just followed the solution step by step and obtained that result...

Comment: If still you are curious why S exists define $b_n={{F_n}\over{10^n}}$ and calculate $lim_{n\to\infty}{{b_{n+1}}\over{b_n}}$.

Comment: The point is, you proved one implication: if the sum converges, it has to converge to $9/79$. In principle, it is still possible that the sum fails to converge. A convergence criterion, as you just pointed out, suffices.

Comment: Now I add another reply to imply that $S$ converges.....

Comment: You can edit your very nice answer above with a brief note.

Comment: You're right.....I'm gonna do that in a few seconds!

Comment: No, I’m not interested in such details. Intuitively it’s pretty obvious that the sum exists and I don’t really care for a rigorous proof. This was from a computational math contest by the way.

Comment: That's it!...Thank you for all feedbacks given so far....

Answer (score 10):

Of course, someone needs to prove that $A=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{F_n}{10^n}$ exists. (E.g. by induction you prove $F_n\le 3^n$.)

However, once you prove that, the calculation is straightforward:

$$0=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{F_{n+2}-2F_{n+1}-F_n}{10^n}=100\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\frac{F_n}{10^n}-20\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{F_n}{10^n}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{F_n}{10^n}=100\left(A-\frac{1}{10}-\frac{1}{100}\right)-20\left(A-\frac{1}{10}\right)-A$$

So, $79A=9$, or $A=\frac{9}{79}$.

Answer (score 6):

Use the method of generating functions. let $F_n=0$ for $n<0$. First make the recurrence valid for all $n\geq 0$. Substituting $2$ into the recurrence yields that $F_0=-1$. The recurrence
$$
F_n=2F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}+3\delta_{n,1}-\delta_{n,0}\quad (n\geq 0)\tag{1}
$$
where $\delta$ is the Kronecker delta is valid for $n\geq 0$. Multiply both sides by $x^n$ and sum on $n$ to get that
$$
F(x)(1-2x-x^2)=3x-1\implies F(x)=\frac{3x-1}{1-2x-x^2}\tag{2}
$$
where $F$ is the generating function associated with $F_n$ i.e.
$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}F_n x^n.
$
Up to this point we can regard $F$ as a formal power series or as an analytic function. In fact $F$ has a nonzero radius of convergence (in fact from the roots of the denominator it converges for $|x|<(1+\sqrt{2})^{-1}$ and
$0<1/10<(1+\sqrt{2})^{-1}$). Hence
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{F_n}{10^n}=F(1/10)+1=1-\frac{70}{79}=\frac{9}{79}.\tag{3}
$$

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Interesting solution.

Answer (score 5):

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{F_n}{10^n}&=\frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{100}+\sum_{n=3}^\infty\frac{F_n}{10^n}\\
&=0.11+\sum_{n=3}^\infty\frac{2F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}}{10^n}\\
&=0.11+\frac{2}{10}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{F_n}{10^n}-\frac{1}{10}\right)+\frac{1}{100}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{F_n}{10^n}\\
0.79\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{F_n}{10^n}&=0.09\\
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{F_n}{10^n}&=\frac{9}{79}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 4):

$$S(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^n F_n=xF_1+x^2 F_2+ \sum_{n=3}^{\infty} x^n F_n=$$ $$=x+x^2+\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} x^n (2F_{n-1}+F_{n-2})=$$ $$=x+x^2 +2x\sum_{m=2}^{\infty}x^m F_m+x^2\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}xF_m=$$ $$=x+x^2 + 2x(S(x)-xF_1)+x^2S(x)=x+x^2+2x(S(x)-x)+x^2S(x).$$  $$\text {Therefore  } \quad S(x)(1-2x-x^2)=x+x^2-2x^2=x-x^2.$$  When $x=0.1$ this implies $S(0.1)\cdot (0.79)=0.09.$

Comment: Since $\lim_{m\to \infty} \sup_{n\geq m} |F_n (1+\sqrt 2\;)^{-n}|<\infty,$  the  series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^n F_n$ converges for $|x|<(1+\sqrt 2)^{-1}.$